# Determining min and max values in an ASCII raster dataset using Python?

Tags: python, statistics, esri-ascii-raster

I have a raster dataset in ASCII format. Using Python, I need to determine the `min` and `max` values inside the dataset. I've been told that the header information is key, which contains things like number of rows/columns, cell size, and etc.

Can't you simply skip the header information and read the entire dataset to determine the `min` and `max` values?

This is what I'm trying to do. I'm skipping the first couple of lines which contain the header information, and trying to determine the values from there on. The following is sort of what I have, but need some guidance as I am new to Python.

```
raster_file = open('data.asc', 'r') # Open the file
data = raster_file.readlines()[4:] # Read the lines in the file, and skip the first six lines

for lines in data:
    print max(data) # Find the max value in data
    print min(data) # Find hte min value in data
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using open source or ESRI stack?

Answer (score 12):

You can use numpy.  See the example below.  A numpy masked array can be generated accounting for the no data values.  See the numpy help topic for mafromtxt and genfromtxt

```
Below is a small ascii file with a nodata value of -999

ncols          3
nrows          3
xllcorner      0
yllcorner      0
cellsize       1
NODATA_value   -999
0 1 2
-999 4 5 
6 7 8

>>> import numpy as np
>>> ascii_file = "c:/temp/Ascii_3x3_1nodata.asc"
>>> an_array = np.mafromtxt(ascii_file, 'float', '#', None, 6, None, '-999')

>>> print an_array

[[0.0 1.0 2.0]
 [-- 4.0 5.0]  
 [6.0 7.0 8.0]]

>>>
```

from there it is simply a matter to determine the statistics you want

```
>>> print an_array.min()
0.0
>>> print an_array.max()
8.0
>>> print an_array.mean()
4.125
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. I will give this a try. Is there an alternative way... maybe without the numpy module?

Answer (score 6):

You want raster data statistics.
[See what you are doing in the gui first](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000001s000000) (for homework.)

Then you can use a python window or a [script](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m3000000).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management("c:/data/image.tif", "4", "6", "0;255;21")
```

Comment: Once you calculate statistics, you can always access the statistics through the raster object property too. e.g. r = arcpy.Raster("c:/data/image.tif"), r.mean, r.minimum, r.maximum

Comment: @blord-castillo Cool! Didn't know that. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys

class Ascii_file(object):
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.raster_file = open(file, 'r') # Open the file
        self.max=sys.float_info.min
        self.min=sys.float_info.max
    def __minmax(self,value):
        if value>self.max:self.max=value
        if value<self.min:self.min=value
    def getMinMax(self):
        data = self.raster_file.readlines()
        data_values=data[6:]
        nodata=float(data[5].split()[1])
        for line in data_values:
            values=line.split(" ")
            for value in values:
                value=float(value)
                if value==nodata:continue
                else: self.__minmax(value)
        return self.min, self.max

if __name__=="__main__":
    myfile = Ascii_file('data.asc')
    print myfile.getMinMax()
```

Comment: This is sort of what I was trying earlier, but I keep getting errors when I use the split method: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: I feel like the line `data = raster_file.readlines()[4:]` doesn't actually work when it comes to specifying the range. I fixed the error which I was having in the previous comment. This was done by adding `num = data[7]` in the 3rd line. It was then split using `values = num.split()` and was able to find the max/min, but for that particular line only. How can I find the max/min from the whole document?

Comment: oh, my mistake, "data" is a list, "lines" is the string. I've edited the code... I tested it with an asc file. Just copy and paste, pay atention to the indentation.

Comment: now the code handles the nodata.

Comment: You can drop the `if check==True` block by initializing your min/max values.  You'll want to initialize min to sys.float_info.max and max to sys.float_info.min.

Comment: You have to initialize max to sys.float_info.min, and min to sys.float_info.max.  That you your initial min will be the largest possible value, and any value you compare to it will be smaller, and thus become the new min.  Same goes with your max value, it will be the smallest possible value, and any value you compare to it will be larger, and thus the new max.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use numpy (and you really should, it's perfect for this sort of thing), then you will need to:

- initialise your `maximum` variable to a very large negative number and your `minimum` variable to a very large positive number
- [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each line to get a list of strings and use [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004550/converting-string-series-to-float-list-in-python) to convert it to a list of floats
- finally use something like `maximum = max(maximum, max(myfloatlist))` and an equivalent for the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this the other day. I used [`arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000012z000000), converted the numpy array to a list, then iterated through my list via a list comprehension to find the min and max values.

```
import arcpy
import numpy
myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r"D:\NED_93512417\NED_93512417_3DEM_RPRJ.TIF")
p = myArray.tolist()

max_elev = max([item for sublist in p for item in sublist])
min_elev = min([item for sublist in p for item in sublist])
```

Comment: isn't `myArray.min()`/`myArray.max()` simpler/faster?

Comment: @Chad, if you already have the numpy array, then there is no need to convert to a list, simply use the min(), max() etc functions in my thread above.  As you also note, no implied access to Arcpy was indicated.